# Using Visual Studio 2008 with Code Warrior compiler

Tags: c, visual-studio, makefile, visual-studio-2008

New to the site. I am hoping you can help me as I've been beating my head against the wall on this one for a month now.

This is for work, and we are kind of proprietary but I will try to share as much information as possible. We have MPC5674F microcontroller on our main development board. To write code before, we used Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 along with a makefile and gcc compiler to create a .s19 file that is then flashed onto the board. Before, Visual Studio would not recognize `make` command. I went into `C:\MinGW` folder and found 3 different `make.exe` type files. There is `gnatmake.exe`, `mingw32-make.exe` and regular `make.exe` in `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin`. I also found a regular `make.exe` in an NXP folder from the **S32Design Studio**. All of those make commands give me different result. If I change one that is by MinGW, then it gets stuck in the makefile saying *The system cannot find the path specified* to an `echo.exe` command, even though I can once again go into command window and type `echo` and it outputs `ECHO is on`. If I use just `make.exe` from either NXP of the other folder from MinGW, it compiles without errors but there is no file output, or even the process of how it compiled. In our *makefile* we specify to output each file that it compiles and nothing happens. If I use `gnatmake.exe` It gets stuck at command  `gcc -c -Ietc\ -I- -x ada etc\makefile` where it says there is *illegal character* and *target_name is an Ada 2020 feature*. Not sure what any of those mean.

I managed to somehow previously get this to compile before, but since then the PC (Windows 10) had to be wiped and reinstalled. Guys that have set this up are long since retired (before I started) so I am hoping you guys can help me out.

Comment: Please don't embed images in SO questions and definitely don't link to images on other sites, as they can go away then the question cannot be understood by future readers.  Please cut and paste the messages instead, with proper formatting.

Comment: @MadScientist sorry, new to the site, How does one do that? I used snipping tool to snip the screenshot and then copied and pasted it. Is that not how its done?

Comment: I mean, copy and paste the _text_ on the screen.  Not a screenshot ("snip") at all.  Select the text, use CTRL-C to copy it and CTRL-V to paste it (or whatever keybindings your system uses for that).  So that if someone wanted to copy and paste parts of your question into their answer they could do that.  And for people with vision problems, they can adjust the size and color of your question and read it, or even use a reader program.

Comment: The real goal of SO is not to answer your question, per se.  The real goal is to provide a huge trove of answers for _other_ people to search when _they_ have questions and get answers without having to ask.  If your question becomes unreadable, for example because the image linked to becomes unavailable, then it fails at that.

Comment: @MadScientist Thank you. Here is the output at the bottom of the Visual Studios output window: 
" Build started: Project: Service_Layer, Configuration: Debug Win32 
Performing Makefile project actions
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Performing Makefile project actions"
Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\AntonPancheshnyy\Documents\Sockeye_inegrated\nul"
1>Service_Layer - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
 Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped"

Comment: Please edit your question (use the "Edit" link at the bottom), add the output, and use SO formatting to make it readable not just a long run-on sentence (see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for example)  However the problem is that Visual Studio can't find make.  Unfortunately I won't be able to help much, since I do makefiles but not Windows and this is not a makefile problem.  And, Visual Studio 2008 is so old that I wonder if anyone here will remember its oddities and how to set it up.

Comment: @MadScientist okay, thank you. How about this. I renamed mingw-make.exe to make.exe and it got past that issue. Now however, I am running into a makefile error that says: <pre> 1>etc\makefile:132: recipe for target 'clean' failed <code>

Comment: Odd because you said you ran `make` from the command line and it worked so I don't know why you would need to rename from `mingw-make` to `make`.  Did you mistype `make` when you meant `mingw-make` in your question?  Anyway, you need to edit your question to add examples etc. because the formatting in comments cannot work with multiple lines etc.  But, if you have a different issue it might be better to start a new question.

Comment: @MadScientist I cannot seem to edit the comments anymore. And the CTRL-Q for example does not seem to change the comments. Do I need to use a specific browser? I am on chrome. Also there are 3 (`<something>make.exe`) that I found in minGW directory. If I change any of those to just make.exe, they all give different result. I always just typed make in cmd.

Comment: I didn't say edit the _comments_.  That won't help because comments can't be formatted, so editing the comments still won't let it be formatted.  You should edit your _question_.  There is a set of links "Share Edit Follow Close Flag" under your question, above the comments.  Choose "Edit" and you can make edits to your question.

Comment: @MadScientist I think its edited. Thanks for being patient with me.

Comment: You need to get a handle on this.  First, `gnatmake` is a special version of make for compiling Ada code; is your code written in Ada?  If not you should ignore that (you can google _gnatmake_ to learn more).  Second, you should run each of the different make programs with the `--version` option and see what type of make they are and what version they are.  Third, you need to determine what kind of make your makefile is written for, and what tools it wants to use.  Unfortunately, building on Windows is much harder than on POSIX systems like Linux and MacOS.  There's much more to set up.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I managed to get it to work. How, I am not entirely sure. I did wind up editing my commands for linux inside the makefile to have quotes around them because Windows kept removing slashes from the path written in the makefile. Also I provided a path to the Unix utilities and the make.exe to `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin` instead of `C:\MinGW\bin`. I also had to add the same path to the `$Path` variable in *Environmental Variable* The code compiles now and seems to work after flashing it onto our system. My hope now is the instructions I wrote for anyone else to do this will work and I didn't forget something.